# Design need of checksum fields at multiple "TCP/IP" model layers ? are they really redundant ?

Tags: tcp, protocols, network-protocols, checksum

Design need of checksum fields at multiple "TCP/IP" model layers ? are they really redundant ?

let us take one example,

in L1: Ethernet-II, we have 4 bytes FCS field, 
 in L2: Ipv4 we too have checksum, but in IPv6 they have omitted checksum and off-loaded to
    upper layers.
 in L3: TCP/UDP both mandates checksum field and further cause performance delay.

So, if IPv6's design to offload the checksum to uppper layers was a good design, then can we ignore L2 and above checksums as L1 FCS (frame check sequence) has already covered the integrity ?

Comment: L1/L2 checksum is only for one segment of a physical link, surely?  It's not going to help much when there's a dozen dodgy routers, a dial-up modem, a fiber-optic cable and a satellite link in an assortment of end-to end routes.

Answer (score 1):

No, because remember layers are independent of of each other. You don't truly know if you will have a FCS in the lower levels. This isn't as important for specific deployments but it is important for the longevity of a protocol. Second the various checksums in each protocol have their own problems. Examples:
http://noahdavids.org/self_published/CRC_and_checksum.html